# GCD async block & EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

This crash is fairly rare, but it has happened often enough to convince me I'm doing it wrong.

It's an API call performed using both main-thread async dispatch and barrier dispatch on a custom concurrent queue (the barrier is used because we're modifying data that is read elsewhere, via non-barrier calls to the same queue).

The objective is to make the HTTP request asynchronously, and then fire off a dispatch_barrier_async to handle the resulting data.

The crash is happening when the dispatch_barrier_async call is copying the variables that are used in the passed block. I suppose that the variable has been deallocated before it gets used in the block, but given how I'm declaring it (as a __block variable) I don't see how that could be happening (unless the problem is with the other side of the assignment operator...).

Here's the stack trace:

```
#0  0x00004f44 in __Block_byref_object_copy_ at /blah/ABEvent.m:156
#1  0x0000582d in __copy_helper_block_ at /blah/ABEvent.m:191
#2  0x02cf3be2 in _Block_call_copy_helper ()
#3  0x02cf3681 in _Block_copy_internal ()
#4  0x02c25526 in _dispatch_Block_copy ()
#5  0x02c26802 in dispatch_barrier_async ()
#6  0x00004e71 in __18+[ABEvent fetch]_block_invoke at /blah/ABEvent.m:159
#7  0x00056e77 in __88-[ABClient get:parameters:success:failure:]_block_invoke_2 at /blah/ABClient.m:375
#8  0x02c2553f in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#9  0x02c37014 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#10 0x02c277d5 in _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF ()
#11 0x02facaf5 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#12 0x02fabf44 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#13 0x02fabe1b in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#14 0x02f517e3 in GSEventRunModal ()
#15 0x02f51668 in GSEventRun ()
#16 0x01ef1ffc in UIApplicationMain ()
#17 0x0005164d in main at /blah/main.m:3
#18 0x00002db5 in start ()
```

And the code:

```
+ (void)fetch {
    ABBlock _success = ^(ABMessage *m) {

        __block NSMutableArray *fetched = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:m.params[@"live"]];
        [fetched addObjectsFromArray:m.params[@"soon"]]; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS (top of stack)

        dispatch_barrier_async([ABEvent eventQueue], ^{  // CRASHED IN BLOCK INVOKE (stack line 6)
            NSMutableArray *events = [NSMutableArray array];

            for (NSDictionary *d in fetched) {
                [events addObject:[ABEvent eventWithDictionary:d]];
            }

            AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
            appDelegate.events = events;

            events = nil;
        });
    };

    [[ABClient sharedInstance] events:_success failure:nil];
}
```

Upstream:

```
-(void)events:(ABBlock)success failure:(ABBlock)failure {
    NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[ABUser loggedInUser]? [ABUser loggedInUser].name : @"no"];
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"loggedIn": params};

    [self get:@"events/live.json" parameters:dict success:success failure:failure];
}

- (void)get:(NSString *)path
 parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
    success:(ABBlock)success
    failure:(ABBlock)failure

    __block ABBlock blockSuccess = success;
    __block ABBlock blockFailure = failure;
    NSString *blockPath = path;
    NSDictionary *blockParameters = parameters;

    AFHTTPSuccessBlock _success = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *request, id response) {
        if (blockSuccess) {
            ABMessage *msg = [ABMessage messageWithObject:response];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                blockSuccess(msg);
            });
        }

    };
}

Elsewhere:

typedef void (^ABBlock) (ABMessage *);
```

Is there anything obviously wrong with how the variables are being used by the barrier_async block? I'm wondering if I should be copying the message (*m) being passed in as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a strong reference to it, eg:

```
        ABMessage *msg = [ABMessage messageWithObject:response];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            ABMessage *m = msg;
            blockSuccess(m);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, Jano. Are those __block re-declarations (blockSuccess, etc) useful, in the wrong spot, or ...? They were intended to prevent early deallocation.

Comment: dispatch_async is block aware, meaning it will capture the blocks passed to it (the __block serves no purpose). It also captures objects so I don't know why it is crashing. You should reject the answer and see if anyone else sheds any light on this.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need the `__block` specifier on this line:

  ```
  __block NSMutableArray *fetched = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:m.params[@"live"]];
  ```

When you specify `__block` specifier for Obj-C objects, they are not retained automatically. Since you don't need `fetched` to be mutable inside the block, you don't need to specify `__block`. (Bonus question: How would you go about this if you wanted to overwrite the value of `fetched` array?)

- You don't need to specify __block on `success` and `failure` blocks:

  ```
  ABBlock blockSuccess = success;
  ABBlock blockFailure = failure;
  ```

should suffice. When _success block is copied, it will in turn copy the success and failure blocks. I'm not even sure what happens if you specify `__block` specifier on a block (perhaps it's a no-op - would be a good exercise to find out), but there's no need for it.

Side note: There is no need to copy `ABMessage *msg` - block will add a strong reference to it.

Comment: Since success & failure are passed in a parameters to get, is it necessary to re-assign them to blockSuccess & blockFailure before using them in another block?

Comment: Actually, no, it doesn't matter if you assign them to a local var.

Comment: " When _success block is copied" -- does this require a specific copy, in this case (as svena suggests above)?

Comment: No. Whatever method uses `AFHTTPSuccessBlock _success` block will do a copy (you should check that it does). That copy will in turn copy your block. So you don't need to explicitly copy your inner blocks.

Comment: Hmm. Well, all of the re-assigments in the sample code were introduced to try and fix the occasional crashing; originally there were none (everything was just done inside each of the async blocks, using the unchanged parameters passed to the parent method). Something wasn't working with that approach. The debugger variables captured on crash from the current version suggest that fetch's m is going out of scope by the time fetch's barrier_async block is executed, fwiw (it has an empty reference, while everything else points to a valid object with data).

Comment: But why would that cause a crash? there is no reference to `m` inside the barrier_async block.

Comment: The fetched declaration and addObject call both used to be inside the block; I moved them to try and fix this. Unfortunately I can't say whether the memory state looked the same between those crashes and these, but the crashes were similar.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29316/discussion-between-sounder-michael-and-mar0ux)

Comment: @Mar0ux I agree about removing all __block storage specifier, they are not needed here. But I think you are wrong when you say "when you specify __block objects are not retained". From Apple documentation: "__block variables live in storage ... cut ... Thus, the storage will survive the destruction of the stack frame if any copies of the blocks declared within the frame survive beyond the end of the frame". Because of local variables are strong by default, if the variable survive, it will continue to retain the heap allocated object until a block refers to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying this block into heap by manually doing:

```
[[ABClient sharedInstance] events:[_success copy] failure:nil];
```

Since you are invoking `success` in another `dispatch_async` your block that you declared in `+fetch` must be copied into heap before you dispatch.

Comment: How does the copy example above relate to Apple's documentation:

"You can copy and release blocks using C functions:

Block_copy();
Block_release();

To avoid a memory leak, you must always balance a Block_copy() with Block_release()."

Comment: there shouldn't be a need to explicitly copy `ABBlock _success` block since (presumably) `AFHTTPSuccessBlock _success` will be copied, which in turn will copy the former block.

Comment: I was under impression that you are running it with ARC. Since blocks are treated as objects, compiler will take care of the releasing.

Comment: @Mar0ux raises a valid point. It should (presumably) be copied.